# What is $ \lim_{x\to\pi} \frac {1+\cos{x}}{{x-\pi}}$?

Tags: calculus

How do I solve it? Is there some crafty algebraic step I need to follow? I'm guessing it's $\pi$ in the end..
$$ \lim_{x\to\pi} \frac {1+\cos{x}}{{x-\pi}}$$

Note: L'Hopital's rule and derivatives are not allowed

Comment: Are you allowed to use L'Hospital's Rule for this problem? (Although it can be done without)

Comment: Not allowed, It would have been easier that way probably

Comment: It will be visually better if you let $x-\pi=u$. Then of course you would have $u \to 0$. Then, divide and multiply by $1+\cos u$. Use the fact that $\sin^2u+\cos^2u=1$ and finally use $\lim_{u \to 0} \frac{\sin u}{u} =1$

Comment: The handwavy solution is to substitute x =  (u+pi), use the polynomial expansion of cos(x), throw away the higher order terms and see what happens.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, No L'Hospital. Here is the set up: Set $x-\pi=t$ and the limit expression becomes $$ \lim_{t\to 0} \frac {1+\cos({t+\pi})}{t}$$ Now using $\cos(A+B)=\cos(A)\cos(B)-\sin(A)\sin(B)$ you can rewrite numerator as $1+\cos(t)\cos(\pi)-\sin(t)\sin(\pi)$ and since $\sin(\pi)=0$, the new limit becomes: 
$$ \lim_{t\to 0} \frac {1-\cos(t)}{t}$$ This is of course still indeterminate. Multiply top and bottom by the conjugate of the numerator and resort to standard limits to finish the problem. Please give it a try from here...

Here is an alternative, rewrite the limit as $$ \lim_{x\to\pi} \frac {\cos{x}-\cos\pi}{{x-\pi}}$$ and use the limit definition of the derivative of cosine (if that is allowed by your instructor?)

Comment: I'm guessing it's something using $\lim_{x\to0} \frac{1-\cos(x)}{x} = 0$

Comment: It is $0$ but don't guess, calculate it...By the way, towards my second hint, if you take the derivative of $cosx$ and plug in $\pi$, what do you get?

Comment: I am unclear on the substitution part. What makes the limit with $t$ have the equivalent results as the limit with $x$?

Comment: @FateMetric Got class now, will comment later

Comment: @FateMetric. With limits you are allowed to make a substitution on the variable if you make the same substitution in the limit. That way you create a new limit that has the same outcome as the given limit. A very easy example is this one: $ \lim_{x\to0} \frac {\sin{2x}}{{2x}}$=$\lim_{t\to0} \frac {\sin{t}}{{t}}$where we set $2x=t$ and when $x$ goes to $0$, so does $t$

Answer (score 1):

You can do this without derivatives by using trig identities and the geometric inequality $\sin\theta\le\theta$ for $\theta\ge0$.  (By "geometric," I mean that $\sin\theta$ is the $y$ coordinate of the point $(\cos\theta,\sin\theta)$ on the unit circle, while $\theta$ is the arc length along the circle from $(1,0)$ to $(\cos\theta,\sin\theta)$.)

Letting $\theta=x-\pi$, we have

$$\lim_{x\to\pi}{1+\cos x\over x-\pi}=\lim_{\theta\to0}{1+\cos(\theta+\pi)\over\theta}=\lim_{\theta\to0}{1-\cos\theta\over\theta}=\lim_{\theta\to0}{1-\cos^2\theta\over\theta(1+\cos\theta)}={1\over2}\lim_{\theta\to0}{\sin^2\theta\over\theta}$$

Utilizing the geometric inequality, we have

$$0\le\left|\sin^2\theta\over\theta\right|={\sin^2|\theta|\over|\theta|}\le{|\theta|^2\over|\theta|}=|\theta|\to0$$

Hence by the Squeeze Theorem the limit is $0$.

Answer (score 0):

With some trig identities:

$$\lim_{x\to \pi} \frac{1+\cos x}{x-\pi} = \lim_{x\to \pi} \frac{\cos x- \cos\pi}{x-\pi}= \lim_{x\to \pi} \frac{-2\sin((x+\pi)/2)\sin((x-\pi)/2)}{x-\pi}$$

$$=\lim_{x\to \pi}\left(\frac{-2\sin((x+\pi)/2)}{2}\right)\left(\frac{\sin((x-\pi)/2)}{(x-\pi)/2}\right)  = \lim_{x\to \pi}-\sin((x+\pi)/2)\cdot 1 = 0.$ $$

Answer (score 0):

Write $x-\pi=2t$

$$ \lim_{x\to\pi} \frac {1+\cos{x}}{{x-\pi}}=\lim_{t\to0}\dfrac{1+\cos(\pi+2t)}{2t}=\lim_{t\to0}\dfrac{1-\cos2t}{2t}$$
$$=\left(\lim_{t\to0}\dfrac{\sin t}t\right)^2\cdot(\lim_{t\to0}t)=?$$